# /sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Sections/Tagging

Tags: sitecore, tagging

We're using Sitecore 8.1 Tagging feature in our website. We had been facing several issues related to the items/publish of item which are being tagged. While investigation found that the 
**/sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Sections/Tagging**
 is missing Base template. It has value of

> {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} [Item not found]

What should be the template here? Why do I get [Item not found], while this is inbuilt Sitecore feature?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**/sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Sections/Tagging** does not have any base templates. All of the system section templates such as layout, item buckets, etc do not have any base templates - this is the reason why you see {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} in the base template fields.

[image]

Actually **{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}** represents a null template.

Check this post for more information 
https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/add-fields-to-the-standard-template-in-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms